# Python card printer

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-defined-functions, ascii-art

I don't understand why the cards are not getting printed the second time, even though the string "Player's Hand" is getting printed again. Can someone help me to find the solution to printing them again?
Sorry for the previous errors, I just corrected them all.

```
def printCards(playerHand):
    a = playerHand
    print("Player's Hand")
    while a[0]:
        for i in range(0,len(a)):
            card = a[i]
            print(card[:11] + " ", sep = " ", end = "")
            a[i] = card[12:]
        print("")
    print("*****************************")
    return

playerHand = [""" _________ 
|         |
| A       |
|         |
|    ♣    |
|         |
|       A |
|_________|""",
""" _________ 
|         |
| 2       |
|         |
|    ♣    |
|         |
|       2 |
|_________|""",
""" _________ 
|         |
| 3       |
|         |
|    ♣    |
|         |
|       3 |
|_________|"""]

printCards(playerHand)
print(" -----")
#Why are the cards not getting printed second time with the command below?
printCards(playerHand)
```

Comment: The line `playerHand[i] = card[12:]` modifies the list of cards.

Comment: Don't really understand your logic but you are constantly changing the value of playerHand. You also check for ```while playerHand[0]```. Once this is false you exit. Next call to the same method will return false on that while check.

Comment: One way to fix this would be to do a copy once the list using ```_playerHand = playerHand.copy()``` inside your method. And use _playerHand inside your method instead.

Comment: You edited your code and it is still wrong. a = playHand.copy()

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be solved in a much more elegant way if you split each card into lines and print the lines with the same numbers at once:

```
def printCards(playerHand):   
    # Prepare the cards for printing
    lines = [card.split("\n") for card in playerHand]
    # Print one line at a time
    for line in zip(*lines):
        print(" ".join(line))
```